# during install pod i am getting this error

Tags: xcode

Failed to extract git version from `git --version`. Instead I see:

```
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Users/mcbook/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.
See `man xcode-select` for more details.
```

Answer (score 1):

Like all macOS apps, the Xcode app is represented in the file system as a folder, even though in Finder we see it as an icon.

In Xcode’s case its main app folder contains subdirectories that include some command line development tools that are necessary when installing apps that need to be compiled.

When you first run Xcode, it registers the location of this subfolder for you. Unfortunately, it looks like you first ran Xcode when it was still sitting in your `Downloads` folder, and so all your command line tools are still looking for it there.

I’m assuming that in the mean time you’ve moved Xcode – which, as you’d expect, moves all the application folder’s files and subfolders as well – to your `/Applications` folder.

You should be able to redirect all your tools to look in the new, correct location by using the following command line command:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```